# Is there a limit to how big an xml file can be for tinyxml to parse it?

Tags: c++, tinyxml

I have an xml file that is about 42k in size.  Shouldn't tinyxml be able to parse a file of this size.  Looking at the tinyxml source code, it appears to just read the entire file in as a char *.

When I reduce the xml file in size to 7k, tinyxml works just fine.

Is there a definitive limit to the # of bytes that tinyxml will parse?

Comment: How are you determining it's failing?

Comment: 42kb is still pretty small for an XML file. Do you have valid markup? Perhaps somewhere in the 35kb of XML you removed to make it work it contained illegal characters that tinyxml couldn't handle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there's a limit, it's a lot bigger than that -- I've used it successfully on files over 100 megabytes.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the operator >>, you might be running into the 8Kb hardcoded reservation made in tinyxml.cpp in the implementation of

```
std::istream& operator>> (std::istream & in, TiXmlNode & base)
```

(that information is relevant as of version 2.5.3)